# Strange behavior of graphics.MeasureString at different resolutions

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+, resolution

I have noticed strange behavior of Graphics.MeasureString at different resolutions.

For the default resolution (96x96) there is a linear relationship across the different font sizes I tested.

However, if I raise it to 512 x 512, the linear relationship disappears and something really strange happens when using measure string.  (See 4 plots below)

If I leave the resolution at the default size for a graphics object, and measure the font size, here is the relationship between font size and the width of a string:

Graphics object, Default Resolution (96):

Font size (X-Axis), WIDTH of a particular string (Y-Axis)
[image: Width96]

Font size (X-Axis), HEIGHT of a particular string (Y-Axis)
[image: Height96]

However, if I change the resolution

Graphics object, 512 resolution:

Font size (X-Axis), WIDTH of a particular string (Y-Axis)
[image]

Font size (X-Axis), HEIGHT of a particular string (Y-Axis)
[image]

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks you.

It should noted that I am using .NET 4 (Full Profile)

Code used to generate graphs (Change resolution for each type):

```
string str = "6  CN-3 Tie EomgVeo405- 2ss>era09rni IBne 20iopv Atdrsn - Ng72";
SizeF sizef = new SizeF(855, 14.000001f);
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat() 
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near,
    Trimming = StringTrimming.None,
    FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip,
};

Bitmap b = new Bitmap(901, 401);
//b.SetResolution(512, 512);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

for (float x = origFont.Size; x >= 0.5; x -= 0.1f)
{
    var data = g.MeasureString(str, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", x), sizef, stringFormat);
    Console.WriteLine(x + "\t" + data.Width + "\t" + data.Height);
}
```

Comment: Graphics.MeasureString() is pretty broken, replaced by TextRenderer.MeasureText() in .NET version 2.  Otherwise the kind of pattern you could expect from the TrueType hinting algorithm.  Rendering text at point or pixel sizes less than 8 is otherwise pretty pointless.

Comment: It starts 'stuttering' when the width reaches 850.  This is the maximum allowable width I feed Graphics.MeasureString.  As Lasse V. Karlsen pointed out, the darn thing is wrapping. I failed to add the 'No Wrap' flag. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a guess, but the evidence fits it perfectly.

What you're seeing is the string being wrapped onto two lines.

Let's assume the following:

1. The width of the text is linearly proportional to the fontsize
2. The height of the text is linearly proportional to the fontsize

This fits the start of your 512-resolution graph, everything increases linearly.

At some point, the width is sharply reduced by a certain amount, and at the same time the height doubles.

This means that a word was moved onto line 2, which doubled the height (2 lines vs. 1 before), and the string got a certain amount less wide since the last word on the line is now on the start of line 2.

From there on, the width slowly increases again as the part of the string still on line 1 linearly gets wider as the font-size increases. At the same time the height increases linearly, but now at double the rate as before the break, since 2 lines now get higher, vs. 1 before.

At some point, again, the last word on line 1 breaks the maximum width and is moved down on line 2, before the word that was previously alone there, and at that point, the width is again sharply reduced by a certain amount.

If you were to continue your graph, I predict that the width will continue its current pattern. The exact amount it dips down each time is proportional to the width of the word being moved. At the same time, at some point the 2nd line will need to be broken, in which case you get a 3x height and the height will then increase at 3x the pace, and so on.

Comment: While I have not confirmed this - looking at my plots it seems logical as the 'stuttering' happens when the string width reaches 850 - which is exactly at the width of the allowable width I feed Graphics.MeasureString.  Thank you!  I should have caught this, I blame reading until 3am :D

Comment: Well, please confirm this then :) The other answers here tell me that I do not know half as much about text rendering and .NET as I would like to, so I'm probably missing something here. Still, it does seem to fit :)

Comment: It was due to the missing NoWrap flag. The fact that the stutter always happened at 850 was a smoking gun. I did confirm it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be happening because of the hinting/grid fitting algorithms in GDI+. Font sizes in your tests are extremely small in terms of glyph legibility, and, because of that, the rendering engine tries to apply special transformations to each glyph to make it clearer. These transformations depend greatly on the target DPI.

It is also worth mentioning that major increase of the font size will lead to a more 'linear' dependency.

This [article](http://windowsclient.net/articles/gdiptext.aspx) explains these mechanisms in more details with some examples.

Meanwhile, you can try to modify the `Graphics.TextRenderingHint` property and/or try `TextRenderer` instead of `Graphics.DrawString` if that will help you with your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will keep an eye on this as well in the future.